# Running java code from CRON job

Tags: java, cron, sh

Facing a problem while running Java code from CRON job.

I am trying to run a ".sh" file from CRON like this:

```
* * * * * root sh /run-test.sh >> /var/log/cron.log
# empty line
```

and this run-test.sh has:

```
java HelloWorld
```

When, I navigate to root folder i.e. "/" and run command:

```
sh run-test.sh
```

It will run my HelloWorld class properly and gives me desired output.

But, through CRON tab it always say's:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
```

I am not able to Judge what can be the reason for this. Immediate replies will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Please show the content of `run-test.sh`. Cron cleans the environment so you need to set it up (e.g. `CLASSPATH`). Also, are you running a Java process as *root*?!

Comment: run-test.sh only contains: java HelloWorld and yes I am running it as a root.

Comment: Did you make your specified main class before building jar from your IDE??

Answer (score 2):

you might need to change the current working directory for cron.

```
* * * * * root cd / && sh /run-test.sh >> /var/log/cron.log
```

you dont have any absolute paths in your script , so it will be running relative to the working directory.

Comment: Yes, your code make sense +1. 

As, when I tried running my Java class from CRON job with code like:

     * * * * * root (cd /; java HelloWorld) >> /var/log/cron.log

it works fine.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use full qualified name for class in your shell file . For example com.nri.gov.master.ctrl.HelloWorld
like this--

**$JAVA com.nri.gov.master.ctrl.HelloWorld $Var 2>> /var/log/console.log**

Comment: Tried that, but it also leads to same response.

Answer (score 1):

Check following points,

- Set Java home : **`export JAVA_HOME=[path-to-java-directory]`**
- Java requires full package name of class : **`java some.package.HelloWorld`**
- Java class should be available in classpath. For example, to set a jar in classpath : 
  **`export CLASSPATH=yourjar.jar`**
- A working example to set/run a cron :

**`* * * * * export JAVA_HOME=[path-to-java-directory];  /bin/sh  your-executable-file.sh >> your-application-log-file.log`**